# How to trim the data in sql

Tags: mysql

I have created a table.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(5),
    FirstName varchar(5),
    Address varchar(5),
    City varchar(5) 
);
```

in that table i have inserted a data.

```
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID,LastName,FirstName, Address,City )
VALUES ('1','TomBErichsen','Skagen212','Stavanger3','c4006333');
```

Data is inserting

```
1  TomBErichsen Skagen212 Stavanger3  c4006
```

But my question is I have a created  storage element 5. If i entered more than 5
 VARCHAR
all the characters are stored. I have to avoid this. the data should be stored like this

```
1 TomBe Skage  Stavan   c4006
```

More than 5 letters. if i entered more than 5 letters the data should be removed.  How can i do this?

Comment: if it goes over 5 surely it should fail the insert and MYSQL returns an error?

Comment: do you want to use pure sql or with some program language,such as `java`?

Comment: A way around this (providing this is data from a HTML form) you can use `<input maxlength="5" />` to avoid people typing in ridiculously long inputs

Comment: Are you sure that this record is being inserted?

Comment: You are lying @Fire - I got this error - Data too long for column 'LastName' at row 1

Comment: to long data should give exception. MySQL has strange pfilosophu cut too long strings and store it silently

Answer (score 0):

You Use **SUBSTRING()** Function.

```
INSERT INTO Persons (PersonID,LastName,FirstName, Address,City )
VALUES ('1',SUBSTRING('TomBErichsen',1,5),SUBSTRING('Skagen212',1,5),SUBSTRING('Stavanger3',1,5),SUBSTRING('c4006333',1,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know what is the different of char and var-char datatypes. So differences are below.

**Char**

1. Fixed length.
2. Maximum characters length 255.
3. Its 50% faster than Varchar.
4. Char is using static memory for the store data.

**Varchar**

1. Used to store variable length alphanumeric data.
2. The maximum this data type can hold is up to Pre-MySQL 5.0.3: 255 characters.
3. In MySQL 5.0.3+: 65,535 characters shared for the row.
4. It's slower than CHAR uses dynamic memory allocation.

In your question you can use substring like as below.

***SUBSTR(str, pos, len)***

1. STR-A string from which a substring is to be returned. POS-An
2. Integer indicating a string position within the string str. LEN-An
3. Integer indicating a number of characters to be returned.

**The SUBSTR() function is same as SUBSTRING() function**

```
SELECT SUBSTR('Buddhika',4,3);
```

Result Is:

```
    mysql> SELECT SUBSTR('Buddhika',4,3);
+--------------------------+
| SUBSTR('Buddhika',4,3) |
+--------------------------+
| dhi                      | 
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Thanks.